# How to create model with association M-N via Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Stack: NodeJs, PostgreSQL, Sequelize, Express.
I have two associated models (**User** and **Role**) through **User_Roles**.
When I create new user via *Sequelize*.**create()**, how can i fill the User_Roles table to define which roles *(i get the array filled with role ID)* the user have. The roles are already defined in table (roles)

The models:

```
const User = sequelize.define('users', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
  email: { type: DataTypes.STRING(320), allowNull: false, unique: true, isEmail: true },
});

const Role = sequelize.define('roles', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
  title: { type: DataTypes.STRING(64), allowNull: false, unique: true },
});

const User_Roles = sequelize.define('user_roles', {}, { timestamps: false });

// Associations

User.belongsToMany(Role, { through: User_Roles });
Role.belongsToMany(User, { through: User_Roles });
```

UserController:

```
async create(req, res, next) {
    const { email, roles } = req.body;

    if (!email) {
      return next(ApiError.badRequest('Invalid request'));
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(roles) || !roles.length) {
      return next(ApiError.badRequest('Invalid request'));
    }

    const isExistThisEmail = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
    if (isExistThisEmail) {
      return next(ApiError.badRequest('The email already exists'));
    }

    const user = await User.create({ email });

    return res.status(201).json(createdUser);
  }
```

[image: The roles in DB]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamically added methods (according to associations) in the model:

```js
await user.setRoles([1,2,3]) // or indicate the roles instances
```

See [special methods/mixins](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#special-methodsmixins-added-to-instances)